# Winter bash blog posts are not tagged correctly

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, winter-bash, blog

There are many winter bash posts in The Overflow blog posts. Those can be searched by the wording [winter bash](https://stackoverflow.blog/?s=winter+bash).

But we have tag option in The Overflow blog, but it was not linked properly to the post. Currently the [`winter-bash`](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/winter-bash/) tag contains only one post. And most of the winter bash posts are not linked with any tag.

Can all the winter bash blog posts be tagged with the [`winter-bash`](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/winter-bash/) tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All Winter Bash related blog posts should now be properly tagged

> reading on the blog
> want Winter Bash history?
> categorized now